# calling a popup window function from parent not working

Tags: javascript, php, timer

I am creating a game in which players have pop window. I am trying to call timer function from parent to player2 popup

I have googled and put this code in parent

```
var Popup = window.open("player2.php", "bpPopup",'toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,width=420,height=300,left = 490,top = 262');
Popup.focus();
Popup.calltimer();
```

and in player2.php

```
function calltimer() {
  alert('timer  2 called');
}
```

Comment: if I am correct , myWindow.opener refer to parent window , i want to call child window function

Comment: @LawrenceCherone - no. the function is in the child

Comment: 1. any console errors? 2. You may need to use setTimeout to have the function available to the parent: `setTiemout(function() { Popup.calltimer();},1000)`

Answer (score 0):

Attach a load event to the popup and then call the function though the popups `window` object.

```
<script>
    var Popup = window.open("./player2.php", "bpPopup", 'toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,width=420,height=300,left = 490,top = 262');
    Popup.focus();
    Popup.addEventListener('load', function() { 
        Popup.window.calltimer(); 
    }, false);
</script>
```

[See it working](https://jsbin.com/zeqazubizi) (dont forget to allow popups)

Comment: not woking , no console error , it will be helpful if you can show in jsfiddle

Comment: @NeerajVerma Try it now, with the load event added.

Comment: @NeerajVerma Added example

Comment: yes , it is working in js bin , but in my hosting server , player2.php is not updating the code inside function , it is repetitive calling same code , i even tried to run it cognito mode, but old code keeps on appearing

Comment: As-is with the code provided by yourself, the answer answers your question. Please provide the actual code your using as if its nested or in a closure and not a global object/function then my answer won't work without tweaking.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a timing issue: `window.open` can return before the page has loaded, before even the player2 script has been parsed - so the function object doesn't exist yet.

Of course IE, *and perhaps Edge*, waits until after the child page has loaded before returning from `window.open`, so you can call child functions immediately. Adding a `load` event listener in IE actually won't work - `load` will have fired before you try to listen for it.

A workaround that doesn't care about timing in different browsers is to:

- open the child window and record a reference to its window object.
- in the child window, call a function in the opening window from the load event. This is a signal to the parent that the child is ready.
- After receiving the signal from the child, the parent can proceed to call script in the child window.

#### Testing in the parent window:

```
var Popup;
function test1() {
    Popup = window.open("player2.php", "bpPopup",  'toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,width=420,height=300,left = 490,top = 262');
}

function player2Ready() {
    setTimeout(test2,0);
}

function test2() {
    Popup.focus();
    Popup.calltimer();  
}
```

where `test1` is called from a click event:

```
<span onclick="test1()">test</span>
```

The `player2Ready` function uses a timeout to call `test2` to decouple code execution between child and parent windows for the test.

#### In the child (player2)

```
function calltimer()
{
    alert('timer  2 called');
}
window.onload = function() { opener.player2Ready()};
```